# react native mp android chart could not find a declaration file

Tags: react-native

I want to use chart to my react native application so i installed `react-native-mp-android-chart` according it's [official sites](https://github.com/mskec/react-native-mp-android-chart#setup)

According that after installed this chart :
`npm i react-native-mp-android-chart --save`

I added :
`maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` 
to 
`android/build.gradle`

and added `include ':reactNativeMPAndroidChart'
project(':reactNativeMPAndroidChart').projectDir = new File(
  rootProject.projectDir,
  '../node_modules/react-native-mp-android-chart/android'
)`

to 
`android/settings.gradle` .

I also added to `android/app/build.gradle`

this: `implementation project(':reactNativeMPAndroidChart')`

and finally i added these to `MainApplication.java`:

```
import com.github.reactNativeMPAndroidChart.MPAndroidChartPackage;
...

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          packages.add(new MPAndroidChartPackage()) ;
          return packages;
        }
```

But **first** error when sync gradle is happened:

```
ERROR: The modules ['react-native-mp-android-chart', 'reactNativeMPAndroidChart'] point to the same directory in the file system.
Each module must have a unique path.
```

**Second**: of course with this error i can not use this library because when i import `react-native-mp-android-chart` to react native project like this :

`import {} from 'react-native-mp-android-chart';`

in import i can not find any chart like `BarChart` or other and i got this message

```
module "f:/SafaProject/ReactNative/RNAuditMngm/node_modules/react-native-mp-android-chart/index.android"
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-mp-android-chart'. 'f:/SafaProject/ReactNative/RNAuditMngm/node_modules/react-native-mp-android-chart/index.android.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native-mp-android-chart` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-mp-android-chart';`ts(7016)
```

How could i use this chart ? and where is my mistake?